# Не удаётся подключится к серверу, написанному на python socket

Tags: python, сервер

я новичок в теме сетей и т.д. решил написать сервер на python с использованием библиотеки socket, вод код сервера

```
import socket

# Создание сервера
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(('127.0.0.1', 2000))

# Прослушка порта
server.listen(4)
print('Working..')

# Получение информации
client_socket, address = server.accept()
data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
print(data)

# Отправка информации/ заголовков
HDRS = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n'
content = 'Hello, how are you?'.encode('utf-8')
client_socket.send(HDRS.encode('utf-8') + content)`
```

На локальной машине всё работает, но я решил попробовать снять VPS сервер и запустить на нём, Ip я поменял на ip сервера, но к серверу не удаётся подключится, порт вроде как открыт и слушает, но подключение не происходит, можете подсказать в чём проблема.
P. S. Для подключения использую яндекс браузер

Comment: Вероятно, нужно изменить настройки файрвола. Скорее всего он блокирует.

Comment: Если не сложно, то подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: Зависит от того, какая у вас ОС (точная версия).

Comment: Windows 10, но я только что его просто отключил, проверил и включил, это не помогло

Answer (score 0):

`server.bind(('127.0.0.1', 2000))` значит порт открыт только на 127.0.0.1. Чтоб открыть на внешнем адресе нужно `server.bind(('0.0.0.0', 2000))`

Comment: Да, я поменял, только как я понял надо не просто 0.0.0.0, а соответственно свой ip, и даже если всё сделать как вы сказали, всё равно не подключается

Comment: Надо поставить именно 0.0.0.0

Comment: Попробовал поставить 0.0.0.0, порт сделал 12345, не заработало